# user defined function producing warnings in R

Tags: r, function, argument-passing, type-conversion, mean

I would like to write a function which takes 3 arguments and calculates the mean based on the value of the arguments. The dataframe I'm using has 3 variables out of which the mean uses one of them and it holds numeric values. When I do `mean(df$v1, na.rm=TRUE)` I get a warning saying:

```
Warning message:
In mean.default(df$v1, na.rm = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

I tried to do `mean(df$as.numeric(as.character(v1)), na.rm = TRUE)`

```
Error in mean(df$as.numeric(as.character(v1)), na.rm = TRUE) : 
  attempt to apply non-function
```

Not sure how to deal with this.

Answer (score 1):

If you get an warning for `mean(df$v1, na.rm=TRUE)` then it probably means you have made an error in data entry that resulted in numbers getting coerced to characters and then to factors. Try:

```
str(df$v)
```

I predict you will find that to be a factor column. You can change it back to numeric with:

```
df$v1 <- as.numeric(as.character(df$v1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
mean(as.numeric(as.character(df$v1)), na.rm = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

The suggested way to convert factors to numeric is to use levels.  From the as.factor help file:

> In particular, as.numeric applied to a factor is meaningless, and may happen by implicit coercion. To transform a factor f to approximately its original numeric values, as.numeric(levels(f))[f] is recommended and slightly more efficient than as.numeric(as.character(f)).

Example:

```
> x=factor(10:20)
> as.numeric(levels(x))[x]
 [1] 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Note this is logically the same as:

```
> x=factor(10:20)
> as.numeric(levels(x))[as.numeric(x)]
 [1] 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

As factors are integers internally.

Comment: Well, yeah, we who have read the `help()` page do know that but then, smarty-pants, why did you not write: `as.numeric( levels(x) )[ as.integer(x)]`, eh?